# SQL Server 2016 - Calculating remaining stock quantity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table like this:

[image: Table Layout]

As you can see, I have a column called remaining_stock that is correct for the first line of each item but NOT for the subsequent lines. The first line is straight forward as you can simply subtract the order-quantity from initial_stock..

What I want to achieve is to get a remaining_stock column that looks like this:

[image: Desired Result]

I though of using row_number and then joining back to the same table using the row numbers.. but that doesn't quite work either. can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
select 1 as line, 123 as item, 5 as order_quantity,10 as intial_stock
union all
select 2 as line, 123 as item, 3 as order_quantity,10 as intial_stock
union all
select 3 as line, 123 as item, 1 as order_quantity,10 as intial_stock
union all
select 4 as line, 234 as item, 5 as order_quantity,15 as intial_stock
union all
select 5 as line, 234 as item, 3 as order_quantity,15 as intial_stock
union all
select 6 as line, 234 as item, 1 as order_quantity,15 as intial_stock
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small matter using the window function Sum() over

**Example**

```
Select * 
      ,Remaining_Stock = intial_stock - sum(Order_Quantity) over (Partition By Item Order by Line)
 from YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
line    item    order_quantity  intial_stock    Remaining_Stock
1       123     5               10              5
2       123     3               10              2
3       123     1               10              1
4       234     5               15              10
5       234     3               15              7
6       234     1               15              6
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I though I tried that already.. but it works a treat.

Comment: @Harry I suspect you were over-thinking it :)  Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Hello the previous answer using sum and partition is by far the simplest and fastest compared to this answer, but maybe this answer using recursion in Sql Server can help someone too:

```
with data as (
select *, row_number()over(partition by item order by line) as rn 
from your_table
), rcte as (
select rn, line, item, order_quantity, intial_stock, intial_stock- order_quantity as rem_stock
from data
where rn=1
union all
select  d.rn, d.line, d.item, d.order_quantity, d.intial_stock, rc.rem_stock-d.order_quantity
from data d join rcte rc 
on d.rn=rc.rn+1 and d.item=rc.item
)
select line, item, order_quantity, intial_stock, rem_stock
 from rcte
order by 1,2
```

Hope it helps.