# How can I sum all child's values into the same column for the respective parent row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a query (SQL Server 2016) to get the cost of a recipe.
The recipe can be a mixture of subrecipes and raw items. A subrecipe can have multiple nested levels and again, its ingredients can be of type raw or subrecipes. (Recipe > Subrecipe > raw items).

Using a recursive CTE, I already exploded the recipe to all it's subrecipes and raw items.

However, I'm having problems to find a way to roll-up raw items costs from the lowest level, to the intermediate subrecipes, and finally, up to the 1st level. Subrecipes never have costs attached. instead, they need to be calculated at the moment based on the cost of its childs.

A subrecipe cost should be the SUM of all its child costs (raw or subrecipes). But before this subrecipe's cost can be rolled upwards, it needs an additional calculation. The formula for subrecipe costs is something like this:
( SUM() / HowMuchThisSubRecipeMakes ) * HowMuchOfThisSubRecipeIsUsed

I've been trying subqueries in join statements, and lately was trying SUM() OVER ... clauses; but I still can't get to the expected results.

-- See on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d6fcd/1/0

-- TEST SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE RecipeExploded (
        IngrSeq NVARCHAR(50)
        ,RecipeLevel SMALLINT
        ,IngrType NVARCHAR(1)
        ,IngrName NVARCHAR(100)
        ,IngrAmountStd FLOAT
        ,IngrUnitCostStd FLOAT
        ,ParentName NVARCHAR(100)
        ,ParentRecipeMakesStd FLOAT
        ,ForDEBUGExpectedResultForPTypes NVARCHAR(15)
        )

      INSERT INTO RecipeExploded
      (IngrSeq, RecipeLevel, IngrType, IngrName, IngrAmountStd, IngrUnitCostStd, ParentName, ParentRecipeMakesStd, ForDEBUGExpectedResultForPTypes)
      VALUES
         ('1', 1, 'R', 'RICE', 0.438, 1.134, '(FINAL DISH)', 1, 'n/a')

      ,  ('2', 1, 'P', 'P-BLACK BEANS', 0.031, NULL, '(FINAL DISH)', 1, '0.019')
      ,  ('2.1', 2, 'R', 'BLACK BEANS CAN', 0.625, 0.770, 'P-BLACK BEANS', 0.875, 'n/a')
      ,  ('2.2', 2, 'P', 'P-HOT SALSA', 0.008, NULL, 'P-BLACK BEANS', 0.875, '0.049')
      ,  ('2.2.1', 3, 'R', 'TOMATO', 4.0, 1, 'P-HOT SALSA', 2.5, 'n/a')
      ,  ('2.2.2', 3, 'R', 'CHILI SAUCE', 8.75, 1.105, 'P-HOT SALSA', 2.5, 'n/a')

      ,  ('3', 1, 'P', 'P-CHICKEN PATTY', 3.0, NULL, '(FINAL DISH)', 1, '1.372')
      ,  ('3.1', 2, 'P', 'P-CHICKEN COOKED', 3.0, NULL, 'P-CHICKEN PATTY', 24, '0.457')
      ,  ('3.1.1', 3, 'P', 'P-CHICKEN MARINATED', 6.0, NULL, 'P-CHICKEN COOKED', 0.375, '3.218')
      ,  ('3.1.1.1', 4, 'P', 'P-CHICKEN DEFROSTED', 1.0, NULL, 'P-CHICKEN MARINATED', 16.0, '0.178')
      ,  ('3.1.1.1.1', 5, 'R', 'CHICKEN FILET', 5.0, 2.849, 'P-CHICKEN DEFROSTED', 5, 'n/a')
      ,  ('3.1.1.2', 4, 'R', 'OIL SPRAY', 0.002, 6.974, 'P-CHICKEN MARINATED', 16.0, 'n/a')
      ,  ('3.1.1.3', 4, 'R', 'MARINADE', 0.125, 2.846, 'P-CHICKEN MARINATED', 16.0, 'n/a')
      ,  ('3.1.2', 3, 'R', 'OIL SPRAY', 0.024, 6.765, 'P-CHICKEN COOKED', 0.375, 'n/a')
```

-- TEST QUERY:

```
SELECT
  ex.IngrSeq
  ,IngrNameFormatted = REPLICATE('....', ex.RecipeLevel - 1) + ex.IngrName
  ,IngrAmountStd
  ,IngrUnitCostStd
  ,CostPer1ParentStd = (CASE
                          WHEN ex.IngrType='R' AND ex.RecipeLevel=1 THEN
                              (ex.IngrAmountStd * ex.IngrUnitCostStd)

                          WHEN ex.IngrType='R' AND ex.RecipeLevel>1 THEN
                              (ex.IngrAmountStd * ex.IngrUnitCostStd) / ex.ParentRecipeMakesStd

                          WHEN ex.IngrType='P' THEN
                              NULL
                        /*Here's where I need the help:
                        The formula should be:
                        ( SUM(<the 'CostPer1ParentStd' column of all this prep's childs>) / ParentRecipeMakesStd )* IngrAmountStd
                        */
                        END)
  ,ex.ForDEBUGExpectedResultForPTypes
  ,ex.RecipeLevel
  ,ex.IngrType
  ,ParentName
  ,ParentRecipeMakesStd
FROM RecipeExploded ex
ORDER BY ex.IngrSeq
```

Please see result's column 'ForDEBUGExpectedResultForPTypes' for the expected rolled-up cost for each subrecipe row

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216733/sql-server-2016-calculating-remaining-stock-quantity sum(over) -- is that what you are after?

Comment: You should do the cost calculatuion in the recursive CTE. This is where you have all the necesary information regarding hierarcy and nesting.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, however it doesn't answer my question. I understand I can't do any aggregation in CTEs, so that's  why I didn't do it there... Or at least couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Please try to explain with one or two *expeted values* how you get there... It might help to show the source data... I do not fully understand your sample, but what I get: You have normalised data and managed to write a recursive CTE to *explode* your data to the given input. Correct? It might be easier to compute your values **within** your rec-cte... Or there might be a entirely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Even though my results dont completely match with yours, I think you need to check your debug values or I need to update the sql equations I'm using, 
anyhow the idea is to have a recursive cte go from the leaves to the parents step by step, and then group all the similar records together.

```
;with cte as (
  select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by IngrSeq) [ID]
  ,reverse(IngrSeq) IngrSeqRev
    ,* from @RecipeExploded
  ),cte2 as (
   select *, 
   case when CHARINDEX('.',n.IngrSeq)=0 then n.IngrSeq else SUBSTRING(n.IngrSeq,1,CHARINDEX('.',n.IngrSeq)-1) end [RecipeId]
   ,case when CHARINDEX('.',IngrSeqRev)=0 then null else
        (select p.ID from cte p where p.IngrSeqRev=substring(n.IngrSeqRev,CHARINDEX('.',n.IngrSeqRev)+1,999)) end
        [ParentId]
        ,  CASE WHEN IngrType='R' AND RecipeLevel=1 THEN (IngrAmountStd * IngrUnitCostStd)
                WHEN IngrType='R' AND RecipeLevel>1 THEN (IngrAmountStd * IngrUnitCostStd) / ParentRecipeMakesStd
                WHEN IngrType='P' THEN NULL end CostPer1ParentStd
    from cte n
  ),ancher as (
  select cte2.* from cte2 inner join (
    select [RecipeId],MAX(RecipeLevel) maxRecipeLevel from cte2 group by [RecipeId]) x
    on x.RecipeId=cte2.RecipeId and x.maxRecipeLevel=cte2.RecipeLevel
  ),cterec as (
      select *,CostPer1ParentStd [SubTotal] From ancher
            union all
      select cte2.*
        ,COALESCE(cte2.CostPer1ParentStd,(cterec.[SubTotal]+isnull(cte2.CostPer1ParentStd,0))/cte2.ParentRecipeMakesStd *cte2.IngrAmountStd) from 
        cterec inner join cte2 on cte2.RecipeLevel=cterec.RecipeLevel-1 and cte2.RecipeId=cterec.RecipeId
  )

  select 
    ID,IngrSeq
    ,SUM(SubTotal) xTotal,ForDEBUGExpectedResultForPTypes ,IngrType,ParentRecipeMakesStd,IngrAmountStd
    from cterec 
    group by IngrSeq,ID,ForDEBUGExpectedResultForPTypes,IngrType,ParentRecipeMakesStd,IngrAmountStd
    order by ID
```

My results are as below

```
ID  IngrSeq     xTotal  ForDEBUGExpectedResultForPTypes IngrType    ParentRecipeMakesStd    IngrAmountStd
1   1           0.496692            n/a     R   1       0.438
2   2           0.0356496457142857  0.019   P   1       0.031
3   2.1         1.1                 n/a     R   0.875   0.625
4   2.2         0.0499885714285714  0.049   P   0.875   0.008
5   2.2.1       1.6                 n/a     R   2.5     4
6   2.2.2       3.8675              n/a     R   2.5     8.75
7   3           1.69409175          1.372   P   1       3
8   3.1         0.56469725          0.457   P   24      3
9   3.1.1       3.218698            3.218   P   0.375   6
10  3.1.1.1     0.1780625           0.178   P   16      1
11  3.1.1.1.1   2.849               n/a     R   5       5
12  3.1.1.2     0.00087175          n/a     R   16      0.002
13  3.1.1.3     0.022234375         n/a     R   16      0.125
14  3.1.2       1.29888             n/a     R   0.375   0.024
```

As for example the line 3.1.1.1,3.1.1 match with your results, but 3.1 dont , so if I do the equation manually i get the result from my query for example for 3.1

```
3.1=> (3.1.1+3.1.2)/24*3 =>(3.218698+1.29888)/24*3=>0.564697248
```

And this is not the value that you provided that was 0.457.

So am i making something wrong or did you miscalculate.