# Running Total in SQL including last year end total

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Need a query to select "Running Total" as mentioned in the image
2017 year end total plus Every months new figure should add up to previous total.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL7p0.png "Example"

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216733/sql-server-2016-calculating-remaining-stock-quantity

Comment: How does this differ from just having a cumulative sum?

Comment: Need an ID or months to be 1-12 to make this work correctly in SQL as order isn't guaranteed. or as @mkRabbani did, convert year and month to an actual date.

Answer (score 1):

This following script will work for MSSQL and you can use the same logic for other databases as well-

```
WITH your_table(year,month,partersgrowth)
AS
(
    SELECT '2019','jan', 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019','feb', 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019','mar', 400 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019','apr', 500 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018','Dec', 200
)

SELECT A.year,A.month,A.partersgrowth,
(
    SELECT SUM(B.partersgrowth) 
    FROM your_table B 
    WHERE CAST(B.Year +'-'+B.month+'-01' AS DATE) 
        <= CAST(A.Year +'-'+A.month+'-01' AS DATE)
) Running_Total
FROM your_table A
ORDER BY CAST(A.Year +'-'+A.month+'-01' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

using @mkRabbani solution.. you can simplify it like this:

```
;WITH your_table(year,month,partersgrowth)
AS
(
    SELECT '2019','jan', 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019','feb', 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019','mar', 400 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019','apr', 500 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018','Dec', 200
)

select *, sum(partersgrowth) over ( order by  [year],[month]) as running_total 
from your_table
```

EDIT: As pointed out by comment below.. you want to order by a proper date in the sum part ( I would use order by year and then the month number rather than the month name)

Comment: Id think you'd want to order by year then month  it also assumes the output is in year month order. otherwise you see some odd results: Example: https://rextester.com/PTBLA37148  As it stands no order by is specified so the reuslts could be a bit wonky.

Comment: instead of year/month you need to cast both to a date to keep the sort sequence right, otherwise the order by month will sort alpha instead of via date.

Comment: @xQbert agree.. it's only based on sample data that is visible as columns.. we can only hope the OP takes answers with a grain of salt and adapt it to their own situations. ..

Answer (score 0):

If you use MSSQL you can run the following code

```
with cte as (
select t.*, lag(partersGrowth) over(partition by year order by month asc rows ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) prevTotal
from Table )
select years, month, partersGrowth, prevTotal || '+' partersGrowth as "Need Running Total"
from cte
```